# Select a Column as a Range after Finding a Specific Cell

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I'm using these lines of code to find a specific cell in my VBScript.

```
Set FoundCell = objSheetSrc.Range("A1:BZ1").Find("Device", , , 1)
For Each Cell In Range()
    If Cell.Value <> "*MSP430*" Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

So as you can see the Range() is where I'm running into issues.  Basically, I need to figure out how to select the entire column that FoundCell is in as the range, and then delete the rows not containing "MSP430".

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** - for VBScript

Try this:

```
Dim rngDel

Set FoundCell = objSheetSrc.Range("A1:BZ1").Find("Device", , , 1)

For Each Cell In objSheetSrc.Range(FoundCell.offset(1,0), _
                objSheetSrc.cells(objSheetSrc.Rows.Count, _
                FoundCell.column).End(-4162)).Cells ' -4162=xlUp

    If Cell.Value <> "*MSP430*" Then

        If rngDel is Nothing Then
            Set rngDel=cell
        Else
            Set rngDel = xlApp.Union(cell,rngDel) 'xlApp = your Excel reference
        End If

    End If
Next

If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
    rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Tim, thanks for the quick response.  Using that code I get the error "Object Required Rows".

Comment: Sorry - missed you were using VBScript. See my edit.